# CreateAndSend Invoices User Access

Tags: paypal

So I was able to test CreateAndSend Successfully in sandbox, and have now moved my credentials to the live versions.

I created a new business account for using the live version, and have gotten my api credentials for it.

Replaced API ID,PASS,SIGNATURE with those credentials.

Connecting to svcs.paypal.com/Invoice/CreateAndSendnvoice.

and an error I'm getting back is user is not allowed to perform this action.

I set the merchant and payeremail to my email (I tried the paypal email and then the api1 email)

I was wondering if my paypal account needs to be verified to do this API call.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on this. Having my business account verified fixed the "user is not allowed to perform this action" problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a live app id and that it is approved for this feature.

Comment: Hi Chad. The App is approved. but I was wondering what do I need to check to do this feature? I checked online invoices in the app. I was hoping that would allow me to use this particular feature.

Comment: This should allow you to send invoices then.  You may want to open up a ticket with MTS www.paypal.com/mts and provide us with the request you are sending and your app id so that we can look to see what it is approved for.